Oven temperature
This question is a crosspost from this one on another StackExchange subsite due to the recommendation given there. The question arose in the kitchen, not while doing homework.
The motivation
Consider an oven with non-overheating isothermal heating elements as (only) walls in a cold environment.
Consider a point within the oven. If the oven is closed, this point should eventually become as hot as the walls. If the oven is open, the wall temperature should only be reached up to a small difference due to the cooling influence of the oven's cold enviroment.
The model
Take a manifold $M$ as oven. Solve the heat equation under constraints like $f(x,t)=k$ Kelvin for all $t≥0$ and $x∈M$ in the manifold (resp. on its convex hull) (and some less interesting constraints like that the oven walls are initially hotter than its interior).
The hypothesis
If $M$ is isomorphic to a hypersphere, for an inner point $y$, $\lim_{t \to \inf} f(t,y)$ should be $k$ Kelvin.
Else if $M$ is isomorphic to a point, we should get $k−ε$ Kelvin as limit for $ε>0$ (with $x$ being an inner point of the convex hull).
My background
I've heard a course on PDEs long ago from a purely mathematical viewpoint and do not have relevant knowledge in physics.
The question
Is the hypothesis correct and how do I prove it resp. which literature considers such sort of problems? Note that we would like to have a result in the limit valid for every isomorphic "oven", so we have some kind of topological component as well as a limit consideration.
An ansatz
Could we somehow use Cauchy's integral formula for this Dirichlet-like problem to get the temperature of $y$ as contour integral "running" over the (equally hot) closed walls? But how could we guarantee the unique solvability of the heat equation and the solution's complex analyticity (to being able to use Cauchy' s integration formula)?

The solution in flat euclidean space with constant isotropic temperature conduction tensor $\sigma$ (constant mediaum density and constant sperical syymetric heat conduction tensor ) is the solution of the heat equation
$$\partial_t T(t,x) = \sigma \Delta T(t,x), \quad t \ge 0$$
with start condition
$$T(0,x)=0$$
and boundary condition
$$T(t,x\in M) = T_0$$
for $t\to \infty$  the stationary solution is the solution of the Laplace equation.
The results are topology dependent.
In euclidean $\mathbb R^n$, oven surface enlosed in a finite sphere, the t-final solution is the solution of the Laplace equation with decay like that for point source at x=0:
$$r^{-n+1}\partial_r (r^{n-1} \ \partial_r T(\infty, r)) =0   :  \partial_r T(\infty,r) = r^{1-n} , \quad n>1 $$.
ow
The near field depends  on the shape of the surface. One has to make a multipol expansion in $r,z$, the same as for the electric field with conducing boundary a t constant potential.
If the space is not the infinite $\mathbb R^n$ with boundary value $T=0$, the solution depends on the topology of the outer boundary, too.
More challenging if outer surface of the oven is totally reflecting with Neumann boundary condition. In the extreme there is an isolated sphere with an inner space at constant temperature and a hole acting as sorce of black body radiation.
All this has nothing to do with an oven.  The air as medium does not follow the diffusion equation (medium static, thermal conductivity), but the Navier Stokes equations of thermic entropy flow and mechanical mass flow in a gravitational field.
Independently there is the  thermal Maxwell-Plancks radiation field of photons.
